# What does "expected struct Foo, found a different struct Foo" mean?

Tags: rust

I am trying to build an HTML web-scraper and am hitting a snag that I can't get past.

```
#![feature(libc)]
#![feature(rustc_private)]
extern crate libc;

extern crate url;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate html5ever;
extern crate serialize;
extern crate html5ever_dom_sink;

#[macro_use]
extern crate tendril;

use tendril::{StrTendril, SliceExt};
use std::ffi::{CStr,CString};
use tendril::{ByteTendril, ReadExt};
use html5ever::{parse, one_input};
use html5ever_dom_sink::common::{Document, Doctype, Text, Comment, Element};
use html5ever_dom_sink::rcdom::{RcDom, Handle};

use hyper::Client;
use hyper::header::Connection;
use std::io::Read;

fn get_page(url: &str) -> String {
    let mut client = Client::new();
    let mut res = client.get(url)
       // set a header
       .header(Connection::close())
       // let 'er go!
       .send().unwrap();

    let mut body = String::new();
    res.read_to_string(&mut body).unwrap();

    body
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn parse_page(url: *const libc::c_char) {
  let url_cstr = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(url) };  // &std::ffi::c_str::CStr
  let url_and_str = url_cstr.to_str().unwrap();  // &str

  let body = get_page(url_and_str);

  let body_tendril = body.to_tendril();
  let body_tendril = body_tendril.try_reinterpret().unwrap();

  let dom: RcDom = parse(one_input(body_tendril), Default::default());


  // let c_body = CString::new(body).unwrap();  // std::ffi::c_str::CString

  // c_body.into_ptr()
}
```

When I build this lib with `cargo` I am getting the error:

```
error: type mismatch resolving `<core::option::IntoIter<tendril::tendril::Tendril<_>> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == tendril::tendril::Tendril<tendril::fmt::UTF8>`:
expected struct `tendril::tendril::Tendril`,
found a different struct `tendril::tendril::Tendril`
```

How does one go about converting the body string into to correct kind of tendril that parse is expecting?

Comment: *How does one go about converting the body string into to correct kind of tendril that parse is expecting?* This is not a parse error; the parser is only concerned with syntax. Rather, this is a semantic error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This suggests that you’ve got multiple versions of the `tendril` crate being compiled and you’re trying accidentally to mix them. Make sure any things depending on `tendril` are depending on the same `tendril`.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  My cargo.toml file was pointing to "https://github.com/kmcallister/tendril" which seemed to be causing the problem.  I changed it to just [dependencies.tendril] and it was able to build.

Comment: @mpiccolo: yep, the git version versus the crates.io version. Note that `[dependencies]` `tendril = "0.1"` works too, being equivalent to `[dependencies.tendril]` `version = 0.1`.