# What exactly is considered a breaking change to a library crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, semantic-versioning

Rust crates use [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/). As a consequence, each release with a breaking change should result in a major version bump. A *breaking change* is commonly considered something that may break downstream crates (code the depends on the library in question).

However, in Rust a whole lot has the potential of breaking downstream crates. For example, changing (including merely *adding to*) the set of public symbols is possibly a breaking change, because downstream crates can use glob-imports (`use foo::*;`) to pull symbols of our library into their namespace. Thus, adding symbols can break dependent crates as well; see [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=991c179b87404188ff8cc18c75f66d4d&version=nightly&backtrace=0).

Similarly, changing (adding or changing the version) the set of *our* dependencies can break downstream builds. You can also imagine that the downstream crate relies on a specific size of one of our public types. This is rarely, if at all, useful; I just want to show: everything could be a breaking change, if only the downstream crate tries hard enough.

Is there any guideline about this? **What exactly is considered a breaking change and what not (because it's considered "the user's fault")?**

Comment: By "changing the set of our dependencies" do you mean adding/removing dependencies, changing the version of a dependency, or any of these? (personally I'd rule that using a glob import is bad taste *except* for prelude modules, and therefore only prelude modules should worry about adding symbols).

Comment: Only when your public API is not retro compatible.

Comment: I don't think you would consider bumping the version if the code fails to compile (like in your example); semver doesn't seem applicable here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. "any of theses" -> yes.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: I am surprised changing the version of a dependency could break a downstream crate. I thought the very purpose of Rust's name mangling and static compilation was to be able have multiple instances of the same downstream crate in the final binary. Did I miss something?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Having multiple versions (at least if they are exposed) can cause issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130408/what-does-expected-struct-foo-found-a-different-struct-foo-mean/31130554

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: Yes, sure. However isn't that accounted for already? I mean, if you expose types from another crate, then the part of the crate's API you expose becomes your API. Which is why as much as possible you should of course avoid exposing external types :)

Comment: Example: mixing two versions of `openssl-sys` [is not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40824435/33499). So if a crate upgrades using a newer version of `openssl-sys`, it is no longer possible to use other crates which still use the previous version of `openssl-sys`.

Comment: @wimh: Ah! Any crate exporting non-mangled symbols can only be unique indeed, because to be able to import multiple crates Rust uses mangling to prevent symbol collisions. This may also transitively apply to any crate pulling in a C library (thus sys crates), since C's symbols are not mangled.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a Rust RFC on this subject: [RFC 1105: API Evolution](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1105-api-evolution.md). It's applicable to any Rust library project, and it covers all kinds of changes (not just breaking changes) and how they impact semantic versioning. I'll try to summarize the key points from the RFC in order to not make this answer a link-only answer. :)

The RFC acknowledges that pretty much any change to a library can cause a client to suddenly stop compiling. As such, it defines a set of *major changes*, which require a bump of the major version number, and a set of *minor changes*, which require a bump of the minor version number; not all breaking changes are *major changes*.

The key attribute of a minor change is that there must be a way that clients can avoid the breakage in advance by altering slightly their source code (e.g. change a glob import to a non-glob import, disambiguate an ambiguous call with UFCS, etc.) in such a way that the code is compatible with the version prior to the change and with the version that includes the change (assuming that it's a minor release). A minor change must also not force downstream crates to make major breaking changes in order to resolve the breakage.

---

The major changes defined in the RFC (as of [commit `721f2d74`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/721f2d74cc4daf76f3e49d58fbc6ded55d545e45/text/1105-api-evolution.md)) are:

- Switching your project from being compatible with the stable compiler to only being compatible with the nightly compiler.
- Renaming, moving or removing any public [item](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items.html) in a module.
- Adding a private field to a struct when all current fields are public.
- Adding a public field to a struct that has no private fields.
- Adding new variants to an enum.
- Adding new fields to an enum variant.
- Adding a non-defaulted item to a trait.
- Any non-trivial change to the signature of a trait item.
- Implementing a [fundamental](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md) trait on an existing type.
- Tightening bounds on an existing type parameter.
- Adding or removing arguments to a function.
- Any other breaking change that is not listed as a minor change in the RFC.

The minor changes defined in the RFC (as of [commit `721f2d74`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/721f2d74cc4daf76f3e49d58fbc6ded55d545e45/text/1105-api-evolution.md), breaking unless specified) are:

- Altering the use of Cargo features on a crate.
- Adding new public items in a module.
- Adding or removing private fields in a struct when at least one already exists (before and after the change) *[not breaking]*.
- Turning a tuple struct with all private fields (with at least one field) into a normal struct, or vice versa.
- Adding a defaulted item to a trait.
- Adding a defaulted type parameter to a trait *[not breaking]*.
- Implementing any non-fundamental trait on an existing type.
- Adding any item to an inherent `impl`.
- Changing an undocumented behavior of a function.
- Loosening bounds on an existing type parameter *[not breaking]*.
- Adding defaulted type parameters to a type or trait *[not breaking]*.
- Generalizing an existing struct or enum field by replacing its type by a new type parameter that defaults to the previous type *[breaking until [issue 27336](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27336) is fixed]*.
- Introducing a new type parameter to an existing function.
- Generalizing a parameter or the return type of an existing function by replacing the type by a new type parameter that can be instantiated to the previous type.
- Introducing new lint warnings/errors.

See [the RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1105-api-evolution.md) for explanations and examples.