# How can I add another enum variant in Rust without breaking library users?

Tags: rust, enums

Assume the following enumeration type is defined somewhere in my Rust library:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
}
```

Is it considered a breaking change when I add a fourth variant `Color::Yellow` to the enum? If it is a breaking change (I guess so because of the `match` statement), is there a way to indicate to API users that this type might be extended in the future?

Comment: Since it will break all `match` statements, sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is considered a breaking change to a library crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185023/what-exactly-is-considered-a-breaking-change-to-a-library-crate/41195476#41195476). You can annotate your enum with the [`#[non_exhaustive]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/type_system.html#the-non_exhaustive-attribute) attribute to mitigate the breaking change (it forbids your users to non-exhaustively match against your enum).

Comment: @JonasFassbender: Yes, this linked answer covers my question, too. Thanks for the attribute hint. If you turn your comment into an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, adding an enum variant is considered a breaking change. Read more about it in the Rust RFC 1105 - API evolution [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1105-api-evolution.md#major-change-adding-new-variants).

You can add the [`#[non_exhaustive]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/type_system.html#the-non_exhaustive-attribute) attribute to your enum to warn your users that you may extend your enum with further variants in the future, so adding a new variant won't be considered a breaking change:

```
#[non_exhaustive]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
}
```

This disallows projects that import your enum to non-exhaustively match it. I.e.:

```
match color {
    Color::Red => (),
    Color::Green => (),
    Color::Blue => (),
}
```

throws an error, while

```
match color {
    Color::Red => (),
    Color::Green => (),
    Color::Blue => (),
    _ => (),
}
```

won't.

Comment: IMHO, it is sometimes better to broke users code with new enum variant than to make non-exhastive enums. Compiler would notify users about places where users need add new match arms when they make major update of a library. Inabilitiy to miss handler for enum variant is one of major pros of Rusts match expression after all.